# How to validation input type from $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

How to validate input type in $.ajax, iam not set  tag 
because form always reload an action

before i used validation jquery but, $.ajax is not running because loaded by from

(required, maxtlength or another ni html not working, must be set form)

i must set required, maxtlengt, emailvalidate or another

```
            url:myconnection,
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: {
                account: $('#indi1').val(),
                password: $('#indi2').val(),
                register:'individual'
            },
            success:function(data)
                {
                    var usr = $('#indi1').val();
                    window.location.replace("sign-in.html?username="+usr);          
                }
```

And this is my simple html

```
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Account name" class="ipt-txt" id="indi1">
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="ipt-txt" id="indi2">
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" style="background:green;" id="addindi" >
            </p>
```

Sory about my english :D question

Comment: Could you post the entire function ? on the submit of the form you need add prevent the default action by using event.preventDefault(). This won't reload the page. Regarding validation you can use jquery validation or write the functions to validate yourselves. I suggest using jquery-validation.

Comment: yes i am used event.prevent but i don't understrand example :
$('#idform').validation function  ({
// validate here
});

if i used validation function, <form> wil be activated action="" and event.prevent can't be used and reload

Comment: Can you give me some references, link..
i don't know what a keyword for finding javascript, iam beginner

Comment: Here you go : [link](http://www.javascript-coder.com/form-validation/jquery-form-validation-guide.phtml) Also the top question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-validate?sort=frequent&pageSize=15 will be helpful.